# How to print answer got from discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, exe

how can i use discord command to save answer, and use it

I'm not sure how to do it, but basically im trying to make discord bot sends me
file, from place where it hosted.
after it take path name from a answer, and file name too.
it uses them as a path for the attach command with discord

```
TOKEN = "Tokengg83"

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import time
import asyncio

lib = ctypes.windll.kernel32
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.command()
async def importFile(ctx):
    await ctx.send("What is the path you want to import of?")
# here i reply something like, C:Users\user\Desktop
# it saves the Reply got to use it

# then asks, what file name?
    await ctx.send("What is file name?")

# here i reply like, OverFlow.exe
# it saves the Reply got to use it
    
    file = discord.File(r'Paath it took in first answer' + ' file name it took')
    await ctx.send(file=file, content="Here is your file")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

any idea how to do it? thank you.

that's output i want

so when i do like !importFile
it asks path, i say C:\Users\user\Desktop
then it saves it to use it.
then it asks what is file name?
i reply with OverFlow.exe
then it uses the discord commands to get file from first  answer + file name from 2nd answer

Comment: **Please note, that you can only read messages until your Discord bot is verified.** After, you will need to use slash commands, buttons, reactions and stuff like that.

Comment: yeah, it a bot for my own use to controll some far-away computers.
but yeah, it won't be verified so. thanks for note tho, but still any idea how can i solve the issue i have above? :\

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Are you asking how to wait for a message to be sent as a reply? Cause you can do that using `wait_for`. I don't see why you don't just make those questions the arguments to your command though...

Comment: @stijndcl Wait for is kind of unexpected - that's what I call **code readability.**

Comment: @stysan no? If you're **waiting for X**, how is `wait_for(x)` unexpected and unreadable? It's almost plain English. Literally doesn't get more readable than that...?

Comment: @stijndcl what i'm having problem is storing the answer i got.
like, you know how input works on raw python?
like 
```
age = input("How old are you")
print("You are this old :" + age)

but trying to do that via discord commands

Comment: i'm sorry i've edited it now hope it explains more what im having issue with now

Comment: Yeah, you can just assign the output of `wait_for` to a variable, _or just make them arguments to your commands_. `wait_for("message")` returns the message that you sent.

Comment: @stijndcl It is plain english - I kinda don't expect that in programming. So it is readable. Sorry.

Comment: @BRH No I won't "edit that as an example", I won't just give you a block of code as a solution that you can paste in there.

Comment: @stijndcl yeah, i forgot to remove that.
i've solved it, kinda scuffed way but yeah.